# Unable to connect docker mysql via django

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

I'm using docker as MySQL server, in docker I use:

```
docker run --name what -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mami -p 3306:3306 -d mysql
```

After that I tested it in MySQL workbench.

It works fine with 192.168.99.100:3306 and root/abc123 
but when I try to connect it via django:
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mami',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
        'HOST': '192.168.99.100',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

It gives me `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.99.1' (using password: NO)")` when I run application or just doing `python manage.py migrate`

I'm Using Windows and Python 3.6, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have MySQL running on localhost:3306. Point your Django to that host. Do not rely on IP of Docker containers, it is not guaranteed to be the same (BTW in your example you have 192.168.99.100 and 192.168.99.99).

Comment: @dzejdzej , unfortunately, pointing to localhost gives me the same error

Comment: Have you try to use HOST as 'what' (name of mysql container) instead of static IP? and also change NAME 'what' to 'mami'

Comment: Database name if different

Comment: @HareshChhelana tried both, same error

Comment: seems that for some reason django does not use password on mysql connection ("using password: NO"). You need to figure out why. I'm not familiar with jango but maybe the property name should be "PASSWD" not a "PASSWORD".

Comment: Check out this : https://medium.com/@pierangelo1982/django-with-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-in-docker-30b9385c4247